# frozen solving environment step in installing a package in ubuntu

Tags: environment, conda

I am trying to install [moose framework](https://mooseframework.inl.gov/getting_started/installation/conda.html) in my ubuntu (`20.4`). It has three main steps: exporting path of miniconda using:

```
export PATH=$HOME/miniconda3/bin:$PATH
```

Configuring Conda to work with conda-forge, and channel of developers of moose:

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda config --add channels idaholab
```

and finally installing the framework using:

```
conda create --name moose moose-libmesh moose-tools
```

when I try the last step (installation), I stuck in the `solving environment` step (version of my conda is also `4.8.3`). I do appreciate if anyone help me to handle this problem.

Comment: You describe each step, but I do not see this `solving environment` step in that description. You may want to clarify when in the procedure you describe that problem occurs. Use "edit" to clarify your question.

Comment: Dear @vanadium, I edited my question. In fact, in the last step that I want to install moose, I stuck in this solving environment step and cannot install moose.

Comment: That makes clear when the error occurs. I cannot help you specifically here, but a fully clear question is more likely to attract a good answer.